# Mapkit mapType is deprecated in iOS 16. How to update?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

In my app, I allow the user to select which type of map they'd like, then save/persist that selection with user defaults, which is similar to most apps. I then call this function to update the display type. I've updated this to use the new MKMapConfiguration class for iOS 16 and above. This code works fine, but was wondering if this is how everyone was doing it.

One thing I noticed is that the new MKStandardMapConfiguration is needed in order to get the full DCE (detailed city experience). 3D bridges wouldn't show on the older standard map type.

```
func setMapType() {
 let mapTypeDisplay = defaults.integer(forKey: "mapViewType")

 if #available(iOS 16, macOS 13, *) {
 switch mapTypeDisplay {
   case 1: mapView.preferredConfiguration = MKHybridMapConfiguration(elevationStyle: .flat)
   case 2: mapView.preferredConfiguration = MKHybridMapConfiguration(elevationStyle: .realistic)
   default: mapView.preferredConfiguration = MKStandardMapConfiguration(elevationStyle: .realistic, emphasisStyle: .default) }
 } else { 
//fallback to older versions
 switch mapTypeDisplay {
   case 1: mapView.mapType = MKMapType.hybrid
   case 2: mapView.mapType = MKMapType.hybridFlyover
   default: mapView.mapType = MKMapType.standard }
 }
 }
```

Comment: You can either do what you are doing or you can use only the old API. As long as your deployment target is pre-iOS 16 or pre-macOS 13 then you won't get deprecation warnings.